# iPhone SDK 3.1.2 - Only Bugfix?

Tags: iphone

Apple just released iPhone SDK 3.1.2.

I was wondering wether they changed some libraries or fixed only bugs.

Can someone give me some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can log in to the developer center, just take a look at the readme:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.2__final/final_about_xcode_3.1.4_and_iphone_sdk_3.1.2_leopard.pdf

In short: nothing changed in the libraries, only in the SDK apps